# Detect if embedding page is fully loaded from inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, event-handling, addeventlistener

I want to send a post message from an iframe when the embedding page has completely loaded. How can I detect if that's the case from inside the iframe?

I already tried using an eventListener for "DOMContentLoaded"

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", postMessageFunctionCall);
```

But it does not react to the event from the parent.
Is there a possibility to react to this event from inside the iframe?

Comment: Are they from the same origin?

Comment: Yes they are from the same origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page and the iframe are from the same origin, you can hook the event via [`parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent):

```
parent.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", postMessageFunctionCall);
```

That won't work cross-origin, though.

Because that sets up a race condition, you might check the document's [`readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) first:

```
if (parent.document.readyState !== "loading") {
    postMessageFunctionCall();
} else {
    parent.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", postMessageFunctionCall);
}
```